# ASP. NET Core - Run function when session ended

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

is there a method to run a function if a session ended?
For example: I want to run a method which deletes a directory, which saves temp data for only the user of the session. If the user doesn't do anything for 10 minutes, I want to delete his directory to save space. If he makes after 15 minutes a new action, he become a new session with new directory for the temp data.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple options to do this

1. Pooling (add a javascript/jquery function with setTimeOut of 15 minutes)

> ```
> function RefreshSession() {
>                 $.ajax({
>                     url: '/Home/RefreshSession',
>                     type: 'Get',
>                     data: {},
>                     global: false,
>                     success: function () {
>                         setTimeout("RefreshSession()", 900000);
>                     }
>                 });
>             }
> ```

2. If you're signingout the user the you can use .net core Cookie Authentication options.Events

> services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
>               {
>                   options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(15);
>                   options.Events.OnSigningOut = yourFunction
>               });

Answer (score 0):

```
Task.Delay(SessionTimeout).ContinueWith(() => doSomething());
```